# Grunt Image Compression

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, compression, image-compression

I've been playing around with Grunt and thought it would be nice to compress images with Grunt (as I am already minifying and compressing other files as well). I have got it to work with:

- [grunt-contrib-imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) &
- [grunt-image]

They work pretty good, however, I was up until now using [Compressor.io](https://compressor.io/) (which is an amazing compressor). And no matter what settings I use within Grunt, I can't get the images to compress to a size that Compressor.io outputs (granted its only a 1 or 2kb size difference, but it adds up).

So to the question... Does anyone know of a Grunt image compressor that rivals Compressor.io?

Thanks in advance!!